# Can't compile Bitcoin Core, because Boost library for C++ gives error when compiling

Tags: c++, macos, boost, apple-silicon, bitcoind

So, was trying to compile [Bitcoin Core](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin) from source. I configured and downloaded all the dependencies I needed. But when compiling, Boost library for C++ gives warnings and errors like below, so it doesn't compile.

```
Making install in src
  CXX      util/libbitcoin_util_a-system.o
  CXX      zmq/libbitcoin_zmq_a-zmqrpc.o
  CXX      libbitcoin_consensus_a-arith_uint256.o
  CXX      consensus/libbitcoin_consensus_a-merkle.o
  CXX      consensus/libbitcoin_consensus_a-tx_check.o
  CXX      libbitcoin_consensus_a-hash.o
  CXX      primitives/libbitcoin_consensus_a-block.o
In file included from util/system.cpp:14:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process.hpp:23:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/async.hpp:33:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/detail/on_exit.hpp:12:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/detail/posix/on_exit.hpp:9:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/execution.hpp:19:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/execution/any_executor.hpp:23:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/executor_function.hpp:19:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/handler_alloc_helpers.hpp:21:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/recycling_allocator.hpp:20:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/thread_context.hpp:20:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/call_stack.hpp:20:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/tss_ptr.hpp:27:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/posix_tss_ptr.hpp:76:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/impl/posix_tss_ptr.ipp:24:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/error.hpp:358:
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/impl/error.ipp:35:15: warning: 'name' overrides a member function but is not marked 'override' [-Wsuggest-override]
  const char* name() const BOOST_ASIO_ERROR_CATEGORY_NOEXCEPT
              ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/system/detail/error_category.hpp:116:26: note: overridden virtual function is here
    virtual const char * name() const BOOST_NOEXCEPT = 0;
                         ^
...

In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/posix_tss_ptr.hpp:76:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/impl/posix_tss_ptr.ipp:24:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/error.hpp:358:
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/impl/error.ipp:40:15: warning: 'message' overrides a member function but is not marked 'override' [-Wsuggest-override]
  std::string message(int value) const
              ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/system/detail/error_category.hpp:122:25: note: overridden virtual function is here
    virtual std::string message( int ev ) const = 0;
                        ^
In file included from util/system.cpp:14:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process.hpp:23:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/async.hpp:33:

...

In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/posix_tss_ptr.hpp:76:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/impl/posix_tss_ptr.ipp:24:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/error.hpp:358:
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/impl/error.ipp:67:15: warning: 'name' overrides a member function but is not marked 'override' [-Wsuggest-override]
  const char* name() const BOOST_ASIO_ERROR_CATEGORY_NOEXCEPT
              ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/system/detail/error_category.hpp:116:26: note: overridden virtual function is here
    virtual const char * name() const BOOST_NOEXCEPT = 0;
                         ^
In file included from util/system.cpp:14:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process.hpp:23:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/async.hpp:33:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/detail/on_exit.hpp:12:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/detail/posix/on_exit.hpp:9:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/execution.hpp:19:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/execution/any_executor.hpp:23:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/executor_function.hpp:19:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/handler_alloc_helpers.hpp:21:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/recycling_allocator.hpp:20:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/thread_context.hpp:20:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/call_stack.hpp:20:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/tss_ptr.hpp:27:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/posix_tss_ptr.hpp:76:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/impl/posix_tss_ptr.ipp:24:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/error.hpp:358:
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/impl/error.ipp:72:15: warning: 'message' overrides a member function but is not marked 'override' [-Wsuggest-override]
  std::string message(int value) const
              ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/system/detail/error_category.hpp:122:25: note: overridden virtual function is here
    virtual std::string message( int ev ) const = 0;
                        ^
...

In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/error.hpp:358:
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/impl/error.ipp:97:15: warning: 'name' overrides a member function but is not marked 'override' [-Wsuggest-override]
  const char* name() const BOOST_ASIO_ERROR_CATEGORY_NOEXCEPT
              ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/system/detail/error_category.hpp:116:26: note: overridden virtual function is here
    virtual const char * name() const BOOST_NOEXCEPT = 0;
                         ^
...

In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/error.hpp:358:
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/impl/error.ipp:102:15: warning: 'message' overrides a member function but is not marked 'override' [-Wsuggest-override]
  std::string message(int value) const
              ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/system/detail/error_category.hpp:122:25: note: overridden virtual function is here
    virtual std::string message( int ev ) const = 0;
                        ^
In file included from util/system.cpp:14:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process.hpp:23:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/async.hpp:33:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/detail/on_exit.hpp:12:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/detail/posix/on_exit.hpp:9:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/execution.hpp:19:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/execution/any_executor.hpp:23:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/executor_function.hpp:19:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/handler_alloc_helpers.hpp:21:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/recycling_allocator.hpp:21:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/thread_info_base.hpp:27:
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/multiple_exceptions.hpp:38:39: warning: 'what' overrides a member function but is not marked 'override' [-Wsuggest-override]
  BOOST_ASIO_DECL virtual const char* what() const
                                      ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/exception:106:25: note: overridden virtual function is here
    virtual const char* what() const _NOEXCEPT;
                        ^
In file included from util/system.cpp:14:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process.hpp:23:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/async.hpp:33:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/detail/on_exit.hpp:12:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/detail/posix/on_exit.hpp:9:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/execution.hpp:19:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/execution/any_executor.hpp:30:
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/execution/bad_executor.hpp:35:39: warning: 'what' overrides a member function but is not marked 'override' [-Wsuggest-override]
  BOOST_ASIO_DECL virtual const char* what() const
                                      ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/exception:106:25: note: overridden virtual function is here
    virtual const char* what() const _NOEXCEPT;
                        ^
In file included from util/system.cpp:14:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process.hpp:23:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/async.hpp:35:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/io_context.hpp:43:
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/scheduler.hpp:60:24: warning: 'shutdown' overrides a member function but is not marked 'override' [-Wsuggest-override]
  BOOST_ASIO_DECL void shutdown();
                       ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/execution_context.hpp:335:16: note: overridden virtual function is here
  virtual void shutdown() = 0;
               ^
In file included from util/system.cpp:14:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process.hpp:23:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/async.hpp:35:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/io_context.hpp:43:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/scheduler.hpp:240:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/impl/scheduler.ipp:30:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/reactor.hpp:27:
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/kqueue_reactor.hpp:94:24: warning: 'shutdown' overrides a member function but is not marked 'override' [-Wsuggest-override]
  BOOST_ASIO_DECL void shutdown();
                       ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/execution_context.hpp:335:16: note: overridden virtual function is here
  virtual void shutdown() = 0;
               ^
In file included from util/system.cpp:14:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process.hpp:23:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/async.hpp:35:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/io_context.hpp:43:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/scheduler.hpp:240:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/impl/scheduler.ipp:30:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/reactor.hpp:27:
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/kqueue_reactor.hpp:97:24: warning: 'notify_fork' overrides a member function but is not marked 'override' [-Wsuggest-override]
  BOOST_ASIO_DECL void notify_fork(
                       ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/execution_context.hpp:343:32: note: overridden virtual function is here
  BOOST_ASIO_DECL virtual void notify_fork(
                               ^
In file included from util/system.cpp:14:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process.hpp:23:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/async.hpp:35:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/io_context.hpp:43:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/scheduler.hpp:240:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/impl/scheduler.ipp:30:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/reactor.hpp:27:
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/kqueue_reactor.hpp:193:24: warning: 'run' overrides a member function but is not marked 'override' [-Wsuggest-override]
  BOOST_ASIO_DECL void run(long usec, op_queue<operation>& ops);
                       ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/scheduler_task.hpp:33:16: note: overridden virtual function is here
  virtual void run(long usec, op_queue<scheduler_operation>& ops) = 0;
               ^
In file included from util/system.cpp:14:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process.hpp:23:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/async.hpp:35:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/io_context.hpp:43:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/scheduler.hpp:240:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/impl/scheduler.ipp:30:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/reactor.hpp:27:
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/kqueue_reactor.hpp:196:24: warning: 'interrupt' overrides a member function but is not marked 'override' [-Wsuggest-override]
  BOOST_ASIO_DECL void interrupt();
                       ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/scheduler_task.hpp:36:16: note: overridden virtual function is here
  virtual void interrupt() = 0;
               ^
In file included from util/system.cpp:14:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process.hpp:23:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/async.hpp:35:
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/io_context.hpp:1216:32: warning: 'shutdown' overrides a member function but is not marked 'override' [-Wsuggest-override]
  BOOST_ASIO_DECL virtual void shutdown();
                               ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/execution_context.hpp:335:16: note: overridden virtual function is here
  virtual void shutdown() = 0;
               ^
In file included from util/system.cpp:14:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process.hpp:23:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/async.hpp:35:
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/io_context.hpp:1230:32: warning: 'notify_fork' overrides a member function but is not marked 'override' [-Wsuggest-override]
  BOOST_ASIO_DECL virtual void notify_fork(
                               ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/execution_context.hpp:343:32: note: overridden virtual function is here
  BOOST_ASIO_DECL virtual void notify_fork(
                               ^
  CXX      primitives/libbitcoin_consensus_a-transaction.o
In file included from util/system.cpp:14:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process.hpp:23:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/async.hpp:42:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/detail/posix/io_context_ref.hpp:20:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/detail/posix/sigchld_service.hpp:12:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/signal_set.hpp:19:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/basic_signal_set.hpp:25:
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/signal_set_service.hpp:129:24: warning: 'shutdown' overrides a member function but is not marked 'override' [-Wsuggest-override]
  BOOST_ASIO_DECL void shutdown();
                       ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/execution_context.hpp:335:16: note: overridden virtual function is here
  virtual void shutdown() = 0;
               ^
In file included from util/system.cpp:14:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process.hpp:23:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/async.hpp:42:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/detail/posix/io_context_ref.hpp:20:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/detail/posix/sigchld_service.hpp:12:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/signal_set.hpp:19:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/basic_signal_set.hpp:25:
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/signal_set_service.hpp:132:24: warning: 'notify_fork' overrides a member function but is not marked 'override' [-Wsuggest-override]
  BOOST_ASIO_DECL void notify_fork(
                       ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/execution_context.hpp:343:32: note: overridden virtual function is here
  BOOST_ASIO_DECL virtual void notify_fork(
                               ^
In file included from util/system.cpp:14:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process.hpp:23:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/async.hpp:42:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/detail/posix/io_context_ref.hpp:20:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/detail/posix/sigchld_service.hpp:13:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/strand.hpp:19:
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/strand_executor_service.hpp:86:24: warning: 'shutdown' overrides a member function but is not marked 'override' [-Wsuggest-override]
  BOOST_ASIO_DECL void shutdown();
                       ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/execution_context.hpp:335:16: note: overridden virtual function is here
  virtual void shutdown() = 0;
               ^
In file included from util/system.cpp:14:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process.hpp:23:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/async.hpp:42:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/detail/posix/io_context_ref.hpp:20:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/detail/posix/sigchld_service.hpp:13:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/strand.hpp:567:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/io_context_strand.hpp:25:
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/strand_service.hpp:82:24: warning: 'shutdown' overrides a member function but is not marked 'override' [-Wsuggest-override]
  BOOST_ASIO_DECL void shutdown();
                       ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/io_context.hpp:1216:32: note: overridden virtual function is here
  BOOST_ASIO_DECL virtual void shutdown();
                               ^
In file included from util/system.cpp:14:

...

In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/posix/basic_descriptor.hpp:36:
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/reactive_descriptor_service.hpp:85:24: warning: 'shutdown' overrides a member function but is not marked 'override' [-Wsuggest-override]
  BOOST_ASIO_DECL void shutdown();
                       ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/execution_context.hpp:335:16: note: overridden virtual function is here
  virtual void shutdown() = 0;
               ^

...

In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/detail/execute_impl.hpp:24:
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/detail/posix/executor.hpp:156:36: error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'unsigned long' to 'int' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
        int data[2] = {ec.value(), len + 1};
                                   ^~~~~~~
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/detail/posix/executor.hpp:156:36: note: insert an explicit cast to silence this issue
        int data[2] = {ec.value(), len + 1};
                                   ^~~~~~~
                                   static_cast<int>( )
  CXX      libbitcoin_consensus_a-pubkey.o
  CXX      script/libbitcoin_consensus_a-bitcoinconsensus.o
In file included from util/system.cpp:14:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process.hpp:23:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/async.hpp:35:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/io_context.hpp:43:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/scheduler.hpp:28:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/thread.hpp:23:
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/posix_thread.hpp:84:18: warning: 'run' overrides a member function but is not marked 'override' [-Wsuggest-override]
    virtual void run()
                 ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/posix_thread.hpp:46:22: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::asio::detail::posix_thread::func<boost::asio::detail::scheduler::thread_function>' requested here
    start_thread(new func<Function>(f));
                     ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/impl/scheduler.ipp:137:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::asio::detail::posix_thread::posix_thread<boost::asio::detail::scheduler::thread_function>' requested here
    thread_ = new boost::asio::detail::thread(thread_function(this));
                  ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/posix_thread.hpp:65:18: note: overridden virtual function is here
    virtual void run() = 0;
                 ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/posix_thread.hpp:84:18: warning: 'run' overrides a member function but is not marked 'override' [-Wsuggest-override]
    virtual void run()
                 ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/posix_thread.hpp:46:22: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::asio::detail::posix_thread::func<boost::asio::system_context::thread_function>' requested here
    start_thread(new func<Function>(f));
                     ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/thread_group.hpp:82:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::asio::detail::posix_thread::posix_thread<boost::asio::system_context::thread_function>' requested here
      : thread_(f),
        ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/thread_group.hpp:47:18: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::asio::detail::thread_group::item::item<boost::asio::system_context::thread_function>' requested here
    first_ = new item(f, first_);
                 ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/thread_group.hpp:55:7: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::asio::detail::thread_group::create_thread<boost::asio::system_context::thread_function>' requested here
      create_thread(f);
      ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/impl/system_context.ipp:56:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::asio::detail::thread_group::create_threads<boost::asio::system_context::thread_function>' requested here
  threads_.create_threads(f, num_threads_);
           ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/asio/detail/posix_thread.hpp:65:18: note: overridden virtual function is here
    virtual void run() = 0;
                 ^
  CXX      script/libbitcoin_consensus_a-interpreter.o
In file included from util/system.cpp:14:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process.hpp:24:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/async_system.hpp:22:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/child.hpp:22:
In file included from /opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/detail/execute_impl.hpp:24:
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/detail/posix/executor.hpp:156:36: error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'unsigned long' to 'int' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
        int data[2] = {ec.value(), len + 1};
                                   ^~~~~~~
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/detail/posix/executor.hpp:175:13: note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::process::detail::posix::executor<boost::fusion::joint_view<boost::fusion::tuple<boost::process::detail::posix::exe_cmd_init<char>>, boost::fusion::filter_view<const boost::fusion::tuple<const std::string &, boost::process::detail::posix::pipe_out<1, -1> &, boost::process::detail::posix::pipe_out<2, -1> &, boost::process::detail::posix::pipe_in &>, boost::process::detail::is_initializer<mpl_::arg<-1>>>>>::write_error' requested here
            write_error(ec, msg);
            ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/detail/posix/executor.hpp:324:9: note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::process::detail::posix::executor<boost::fusion::joint_view<boost::fusion::tuple<boost::process::detail::posix::exe_cmd_init<char>>, boost::fusion::filter_view<const boost::fusion::tuple<const std::string &, boost::process::detail::posix::pipe_out<1, -1> &, boost::process::detail::posix::pipe_out<2, -1> &, boost::process::detail::posix::pipe_in &>, boost::process::detail::is_initializer<mpl_::arg<-1>>>>>::internal_error_handle' requested here
        internal_error_handle(ec, msg, has_error_handler(), has_ignore_error(), shall_use_vfork());
        ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/detail/posix/executor.hpp:382:13: note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::process::detail::posix::executor<boost::fusion::joint_view<boost::fusion::tuple<boost::process::detail::posix::exe_cmd_init<char>>, boost::fusion::filter_view<const boost::fusion::tuple<const std::string &, boost::process::detail::posix::pipe_out<1, -1> &, boost::process::detail::posix::pipe_out<2, -1> &, boost::process::detail::posix::pipe_in &>, boost::process::detail::is_initializer<mpl_::arg<-1>>>>>::set_error' requested here
            set_error(::boost::process::detail::get_last_error(), "pipe(2) failed");
            ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/detail/posix/executor.hpp:308:16: note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::process::detail::posix::executor<boost::fusion::joint_view<boost::fusion::tuple<boost::process::detail::posix::exe_cmd_init<char>>, boost::fusion::filter_view<const boost::fusion::tuple<const std::string &, boost::process::detail::posix::pipe_out<1, -1> &, boost::process::detail::posix::pipe_out<2, -1> &, boost::process::detail::posix::pipe_in &>, boost::process::detail::is_initializer<mpl_::arg<-1>>>>>::invoke' requested here
        return invoke(has_ignore_error(), shall_use_vfork());
               ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/detail/execute_impl.hpp:267:12: note: in instantiation of member function 'boost::process::detail::posix::executor<boost::fusion::joint_view<boost::fusion::tuple<boost::process::detail::posix::exe_cmd_init<char>>, boost::fusion::filter_view<const boost::fusion::tuple<const std::string &, boost::process::detail::posix::pipe_out<1, -1> &, boost::process::detail::posix::pipe_out<2, -1> &, boost::process::detail::posix::pipe_in &>, boost::process::detail::is_initializer<mpl_::arg<-1>>>>>::operator()' requested here
    return exec();
           ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/detail/execute_impl.hpp:275:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::process::detail::basic_execute_impl<char, const std::string &, boost::process::detail::posix::pipe_out<1, -1>, boost::process::detail::posix::pipe_out<2, -1>, boost::process::detail::posix::pipe_in>' requested here
    return basic_execute_impl<req_char_type>(
           ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/child.hpp:35:39: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::process::detail::execute_impl<const std::string &, boost::process::detail::posix::pipe_out<1, -1>, boost::process::detail::posix::pipe_out<2, -1>, boost::process::detail::posix::pipe_in>' requested here
    : child(::boost::process::detail::execute_impl(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {}
                                      ^
util/system.cpp:1263:15: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::process::child::child<const std::string &, boost::process::detail::posix::pipe_out<1, -1>, boost::process::detail::posix::pipe_out<2, -1>, boost::process::detail::posix::pipe_in>' requested here
    bp::child c(
              ^
/opt/homebrew//include/boost/process/detail/posix/executor.hpp:156:36: note: insert an explicit cast to silence this issue
        int data[2] = {ec.value(), len + 1};
                                   ^~~~~~~
                                   static_cast<int>( )
22 warnings and 2 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [util/libbitcoin_util_a-system.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

I'm using MacOS on M1 (ARM64) chip. I'm new to compiling stuff from source, and don't know much C++ (but I know some C), so let me know if I'm doing something wrong.

Edit: I was using the latest (1.78) version of Boost.

I installed 1.76 version (it was the only one on Homebrew), but now I have a different error.

```
sidma@Uzays-MacBook-Air bitcoin % make install -j4       
Making install in src
  CXX      node/libbitcoin_server_a-ui_interface.o
  CXX      libbitcoin_server_a-noui.o
  CXX      policy/libbitcoin_server_a-fees.o
  CXX      policy/libbitcoin_server_a-packages.o
In file included from noui.cpp:8:
In file included from ./logging.h:9:
./fs.h:14:10: fatal error: 'boost/filesystem.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node/ui_interface.cpp:9:10: fatal error: 'boost/signals2/optional_last_value.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/signals2/optional_last_value.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [node/libbitcoin_server_a-ui_interface.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [libbitcoin_server_a-noui.o] Error 1
In file included from policy/fees.cpp:9:
./fs.h:14:10: fatal error: 'boost/filesystem.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [policy/libbitcoin_server_a-fees.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Now I guess it tries to find a library that doesn't exist.
My Clang version is `Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)`.

Comment: show which version of boost you hafve , and which version of compiler

Comment: It's a bug in boost, only introduced recently, and which hasn't been fixed yet (https://github.com/boostorg/process/issues/235). I suggest you use the previous version of boost or disable the `-Wc++11-narrrowing` flag in the bitcoin build. Although the code is technically ill-formed, GCC/Clang will accept it then.

Comment: Although I can't be sure that the narrowing itself isn't potentially dangerous, which may be the case if the string this function expects is untrusted.

Comment: rerun the build config maybe? The error messages indicate that no boost headers were found at all (maybe it is still looking in where 1.78 was)